# Jetpack Compose column clickable only in elements area

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, clickable, jetpack

When the code below runs, it overrides the screen elements below. To prevent the elements below from being accidentally clicked, I added the 'clickable' attribute to the column, which should capture clicks. However, as shown in the image, not the entire column area is clickable and items underneath may be clicked accidentally. Is there any way to make the entire column area clickable? Of course I can lock the elements underneath if the notification is visible, but maybe there is a simple solution such as entire column area clickable?

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ShowAddedUserData(
    userName: String,
    userType: String,
    userPass: String,
    onClear: () -> Unit
) {

    val name = stringResource(id = R.string.user_name) + " : " + userName
    val type = stringResource(id = R.string.user_type) + " : " + userType
    val pass = stringResource(id = R.string.password) + " : " + userPass
    val userInfoToCopy = "$name\n$type\n$pass"
    val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
    val localContext = LocalContext.current
    val copyDataInfo = stringResource(id = R.string.data_copied_to_clipboard)

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {  },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.user_created)
        )
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
            .background(color = Color.LightGray),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp), text = name)
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp), text = type)
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp), text = pass)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_copy_content_blue),
            contentDescription = "copy content",
            Modifier.clickable {
                clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString(userInfoToCopy))
                Toast.makeText(localContext, copyDataInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 5.dp),
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.copy_to_memory),
            fontSize = 12.sp
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Button(onClick = onClear) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.clear))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Jetpack Compose Dialog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/dialog), it will properly block interaction with the background.

Comment: You are right, putting everything into alertdialog solves the problem. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I added a formal answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)) and [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Dialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)), which provide an easy way to cover your use case.

```
AlertDialog(
    icon = {},
    title = {},
    text = {
        // This actually is for Text, but you can pass any Composable here
        ShowAddedUserData(/** ... **/)
    },
    onDismissRequest = {},
    confirmButton = {},
    dismissButton = {}
)
```

or

```
Dialog(onDismissRequest = { }) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(16.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    ) {
        ShowAddedUserData(/** ... **/)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can wrap your `ShowAddedUserData` Composable into a [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Surface(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0)). A `Surface` by default [consumes all interactions](https://medium.com/@theAndroidDeveloper/beware-of-this-pitfall-in-jetpack-compose-e39eb0949c6e) in the area it is displayed in.